# Firebase v9.01 - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): productDoc.ref.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I encountered an issue when fetching data from firestore. I can't really figure out why isn't there a collection function under productDoc.ref, and would highly appreciate if anyone could help with this.

I'm using the latest version of Firebase, but still have no access to the prices subcollection if i were to follow docs from firebase v9.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "products"), where("active", "==", true));
  // console.log(db.collection("products").getDocuments());
  const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    const products = {};
    querySnapshot.forEach(async (productDoc) => {
      products[productDoc.id] = await productDoc.data();
      console.log(await productDoc, "ref");

      const priceSnap = await productDoc.ref.collection("prices").get();
      priceSnap.doc.forEach((price) => {
        products[productDoc.id].price = {
          priceId: price.id,
          priceData: price.data(),
        };
      });
    });
    setProducts(products);
  });
}, []);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't chain the `collection` call from a [`DocumentReference` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference.md#documentreference_class) in the modular API.

You instead need to pass the `DocumentReference` to a call to the top-level `collection` function:

```
const priceSnap = await getDocs(collection(productDoc.ref, "prices"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Dharmaraj.  It's still quite easy for me to overlook one of the functional calls. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I found that Frank's code is still not working as await inside forEach will behave not as expected. You have to replace forEach with for loop.

After digging into it for a few days, I found the following code is working.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "products"), where("active", "==", true));
    const unsub = onSnapshot(q, async (querySnapshot) => {
      const products = {};
      for (const productDoc of querySnapshot.docs) {
        products[productDoc.id] = productDoc.data();
        const priceSnap = await getDocs(collection(productDoc.ref, "prices"));
        for (const price of priceSnap.docs) {
          products[productDoc.id].price = {
            priceId: price.id,
            priceData: price.data(),
          };
        }
      }
      setProducts(products);
    });
    return () => unsub();
  }, []);
```